# Does mentioning why I took a break after my MSc affect the chances of admission?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, time-off

I had taken a year break after my masters, before seriously applying to PhD programs. The reason was that I was stressed and burnt out, especially during the COVID times, and wasn't ready for a PhD directly after 5 years of university, and felt like I should take a break. Even though I had applied to 1-2 places due to the insistence of my parents, and for the sake of easing my conscience that I wasn't applying anywhere, I did not put my heart and soul into the applications like I would have liked to.

Now that I have taken a break, and have had time to think about it, stay away from mathematics for a while, or have read some mathematics that I like in my own pace (Nothing hugely substantial in terms of my future plans, but I think I really needed the break, to clear my mind.), I am applying this academic cycle.

The problem is, one program asks me for any situations or circumstances that I had for any significant gaps in my education period, and they claim that the information is voluntary and will not affect my application negatively. But as I understand it, they probably mean reasons like an illness, family emergency, having a child, or some other emergencies that could not be avoided. I am doubtful whether taking a break because I was stressed (of which I have no concrete proof, than my own feelings), or was unable decide whether I want to continue with a PhD then (but the fact that I want to, is as clear as day to me now), would count as a valid reason.

Moreover, I do not understand how can something be used to better understand the application, but still not be used negatively.

So, do you think it's a better idea to mention these reasons in the application, or would it be better to avoid it altogether?

Also, seems like [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55441/146761) would be similar to mine, but it does not address what to do if the program application asks for a reason for the break.

Edit : I realize that I might have potentially miscommunicated the time I got out of university. It was in this (2022) summer that my masters got over. When I mean I took a year break, I just mean that I would only be admitted in the coming fall, and hence it would be a year after my masters; and not that one year has already passed after me finishing my masters.

Comment: What about "due to COVID I decided to take a break for a year"?

Comment: What were you doing in that time?

Comment: @Yanko Are you suggesting me to use that as the reason? It is a good idea, and it would not be exactly untrue (Yeah, COVID did affect me, but not because of being unable to travel, but because of the some of the courses and the stress during the time.) but for the fact that the COVID was almost over by the time I completed my masters.

Comment: @Yanko Also, I realize that I might have potentially miscommunicated the time I got out of university. It was in this (2022) summer that my masters got over. When I mean I took a year break, I just mean that I would only be admitted in the coming fall, and hence it would be a year after my masters, and not that one year has already passed after me finishing my masters.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Read a paper related to my thesis, completed a chapter of a textbook that I always wanted to read but could not complete during my coursework, attended two workshops - one related to my field, one that is not so much related to my field but that I still find interesting. I also applied to attend a mathematics conference, and I was able to listen to (some of) the lectures in the conference online.

Comment: Maybe nothing too heavy, as I said. I just kept up with doing some mathematics I found interesting, but nothing too substantial to, say, write a paper on it, like the answer [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/55442/146761) says.

Comment: @Ron Haha, no I mean besides math. Did you work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Describing the break as caused by "burn out" is probably a mistake. It is a common enough practice that it probably needs no explanation unless asked. But "I felt I needed a break to consider options" is better than "I was burned out from five years of study."

If you let the break go on too long, however, it makes applying more difficult as you start to lose contact with potential letter writers.

And, if there are still mental health issues, talk to a professional so that you develop a coping plan that will carry you through several more years of intense study.

Answer (score 2):

> But as I understand it, they probably mean reasons like an illness,

Stress, particularly stress which prevents you from working or studying effectively, [is a health condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_stress#Negative_health_and_other_effects). Burnout [is also a health condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_burnout).

For the purposes of your application, it doesn't really matter that you don't have a formal diagnosis from a doctor or a psychologist. They wouldn't ask to see evidence of a diagnosis anyway; if they would demand you to substantiate your answer, then this field on the form wouldn't be voluntary.

If you were asking for adjustments (e.g. more time on exams) due to a health condition then that's when you would be asked for evidence.

> Moreover, I do not understand how can something be used to better understand the application, but still not be used negatively.

The main things they are interested in here are:

- If your interruption was caused by something that could happen again during your studies, and
- Whether your interruption has left you "out of practice" with the subject, or if you have maintained your knowledge and skills in the meantime.

It's difficult to say what process they might have in place to ensure that information you provide about it doesn't negatively affect your application. There are several possible processes; the simplest is that they could just "assume the worst" if you don't write anything, but in that case they should warn you that leaving the field blank could harm your application.

I could speculate about other possible processes they might have in place, but I doubt that would be helpful. It certainly seems like there are things someone *could* write in this field which would be worse than not writing anything, which it wouldn't be rational for the institution to ignore. For an extreme hypothetical, if an applicant wrote *"I spent five years in prison for maiming my previous supervisor, Dr. Smith"* and Dr. Smith worked in the department they were applying to, I sure hope it would negatively affect their chances of admission.

So I wouldn't take the words "will not affect your application negatively" literally, rather I think what they mean is that if there is anything in there which might suggest a problem for your future studies, but you're an otherwise promising applicant, then they are more interested in working with you to prevent that problem, rather than rejecting you.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, one program asks me for any situations or circumstances that I had for any significant gaps in my education period

Not going straight to a PhD after your master's is not a "gap in your education period." Especially not if you went straight into the master's after undergrad!

It sounds like they are asking about if you had to take time off in your undergrad or something. I don't think this applies to you and you don't need to answer it with an explanation about burnout.